# Unable to properly read text which has a dark gray/black background in Python

Tags: python-3.x, ocr, opencv, python-tesseract, python

I am trying to use OCR and Python to extract data from a set of images. The image contains tabular data. The problem I face is that I am unable to read the part of the image which has a dark gray/black back ground properly. I tried morphology, playing with gamma and a few image transformations. But they don't seem to help. What can i do to read such parts of the image?
I am using Python 3.7, pytesseract and OpenCV (CV2)
My sample image looks like this- [image: Parts that have a dark background aren't being read properly.]

Here is my code-

```
import cv2
import os 
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
import PIL.Image 
import xlwt
from pdf2jpg import pdf2jpg
import glob 
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join


input_path = r".pdf"  
output_path = r"..."
result = pdf2jpg.convert_pdf2jpg(input_path, output_path, pages= "ALL")
#print(result)


path = "...\\*"
empty_list = []
for x in glob.glob(path):
    empty_list.append(x)
print(empty_list)   #prints path of all images in the folder 


def change_path(image_path):
    print(type(path))
    new_path = path.replace("\\", "\\\\")
    print(new_path)
    return new_path

def  read_and_display(window_name, image_name):
    ori_img = cv2.imread(image_name)
    print(image_name)
    img = cv2.imshow(window_name, ori_img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    return img

def resize_the_image(image_name):           #def resize_the_image(window_name, image_name):
    image_name = cv2.imread(image_name)
    resized = cv2.resize(image_name,(1500,1300),interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)    
    return resized

def gray_the_image(image_name):     #def gray_the_image(window_name, image_name):
    image_name = cv2.imread(image_name)
    grayedimg = cv2.cvtColor(image_name, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    grayedimg = cv2.threshold(grayedimg, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    return grayedimg

def dilate_the_image(image_name):     #def dilate_the_image(window_name, image_name):
    image_name = cv2.imread(image_name)
    dilated_img = cv2.dilate(image_name, np.ones((7,7), np.uint8)) 
    return dilated_img

def bg_the_image(image_name):                    #def bg_the_image(window_name, image_name):
    image_name = cv2.imread(image_name)
    bg_img = cv2.medianBlur(image_name, 21)
    return bg_img


def difference_the_image(image_name):
    image_name = cv2.imread(image_name)
    bg_img = cv2.medianBlur(image_name, 21)
    diff_img = 255 - cv2.absdiff(image_name, bg_img)
    return diff_img


def normalize_the_image(image_name):   
    image_name = cv2.imread(image_name)
    bg_img = cv2.medianBlur(image_name, 21)
    diff_img = 255 - cv2.absdiff(image_name, bg_img)
    norm_img = diff_img.copy() # Needed for 3.x compatibility
    norm_img = cv2.normalize(diff_img, norm_img, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8UC1)
    return norm_img


def threshold_the_image(image_name):
    image_name = cv2.imread(image_name)
    bg_img = cv2.medianBlur(image_name, 21)
    diff_img = 255 - cv2.absdiff(image_name, bg_img)
    norm_img = diff_img.copy() # Needed for 3.x compatibility
    norm_img = cv2.normalize(diff_img, norm_img, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8UC1)
    _, threshold_image = cv2.threshold(norm_img, 230, 0, cv2.THRESH_TRUNC)
    threshold_image = cv2.normalize(threshold_image, threshold_image, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8UC1)
    return threshold_image


def adjust_gamma(image_name, gamma=1.0):

   invGamma = 1.0 / gamma
   table = np.array([((i / 255.0) ** invGamma) * 255
      for i in np.arange(0, 256)]).astype("uint8")
   return cv2.LUT(image_name, table)

def adjust_the_image(image_name):
    gamma = 0.5                                  # change the value here to get different result
    image_name = cv2.imread(image_name)
    bg_img = cv2.medianBlur(image_name, 21)
    diff_img = 255 - cv2.absdiff(image_name, bg_img)
    norm_img = diff_img.copy() # Needed for 3.x compatibility
    norm_img = cv2.normalize(diff_img, norm_img, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8UC1)
    _, threshold_image = cv2.threshold(norm_img, 230, 0, cv2.THRESH_TRUNC)
    threshold_image = cv2.normalize(threshold_image, threshold_image, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8UC1)
    adjusted_image = adjust_gamma(threshold_image, gamma=gamma)
    adjusted_image = cv2.putText(adjusted_image, "g={}".format(gamma), (10, 30),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (0, 0, 255), 3)
    return adjusted_image


def tesseract_call(image_path):
#    image_name = cv2.imread(image_path)
    cv2.imread(image_path)
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
    #config = ('-1 eng') 
    config = ('-psm 6')
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(PIL.Image.open(image_path), config = config)
#    print(text)
    file = open("f.txt","a+", encoding  = "utf-8")
    file.write(text) 
    file.close() 
    return text



for i in empty_list:
    redefinedpath = (change_path(i))
    print(redefinedpath)
    read_and_display("newWindow", i)
    resize_the_image(i)
    gray_the_image(i)
    dilate_the_image(i)
    bg_the_image(i)
    difference_the_image(i)
    normalize_the_image(i)
    threshold_the_image(i)
    adjust_the_image(i)
    tesseract_call(i)
```

Tried various values for "gamma", didn't help.

Comment: Show us your current code.

Comment: You might pick some ideas from https://photo.stackexchange.com/ ; from a programming point of view can you locally increase the contrast when the standard deviation is low ? (to attempt to remove color patches, without loosing data)

Comment: @nicolallias I tried increasing contrast, but doesn't seem to help

Comment: @developer show us the code! we might spot some quirks, typo, improvements..

Comment: @nicolallias, Hello, I have put up the code

Comment: @nkr the code is here! developer, can you output pictures at every steps to figure out the appropriate preprocessing parameters? I wonder if you could try in 3 passes: 1. run with a low sensitivity, to get the text on white background ; 2. mask the readable regions of 1, run the rest on a higher sensitivity ; 3. mix results of 1 and 2

Comment: @nicolallias, I had a cv2.imshow and cv2.waitKey but since i ran it on about 200 images, I removed the show part of it

Comment: @nicolallias Can you show me in code, what you mean by "running on low sensitivity"? Because, primarily, getting all data on a white background will likely solve my issue

Comment: @developer I have nothing but suggestions (I have not written any image processing code since university, many years ago). What I mean by low sensitivity is to use a very harsh contrast threshold, at the risk of loosing the grey lines. The secund pass would process the input data with another set of parameters, increasing luminosity and diminishing contrast, to get the grey-ed datas (at the risk of loosing the ones on white background).